# What does "fly swatter" mean in jazz?

Tags: piano, terminology, jazz

I play a jazz song called "Fly's last boogie" and in the notes there's a star with a description "fly swatter on four". Does it mean I should literally hit with a fly swatter or is this some kind of jazz term?

Comment: For drummers, the brushes are known colloquially as 'fly swatters'.

Comment: @Tim - that's the answer, man. Please post as such with examples? :)

Comment: @Tim That's what I googled but it seemed really strange to me to hit once with a fly swatter on four (about once every 4 seconds in the song). Also I am supposed to play drums while playing piano or what? :)

Comment: I would speculate that in the original recording or perhaps the intention of the composer, the (a) drummer would hit the snare with the brush every 4th beat, and that was an intrinsic part of the piece, obviously a pun with the title. The transcriber or composer made a point of notating that even  a  reduction (?) score or lead sheet.

Comment: Can you post the score or a link to the sheet music?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ok then https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwubCx2m0mVuQXVHQmczX01hbFk/view?usp=sharing  It might be even legal in my country :)

Answer (score 2):

Only clue I have is that drummers use  'fly swatters' aka brushes. It seems odd that the tune needs a brush stroke, so to speak, on 4, but I don't know what happens on the rest of the bar, never having met or played this piece. For once, Google knows as little as I !